# How to say, "I gave myself away"?

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german

So, like hiding a secret and gave it away, in that sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ich habe mich verraten.

Alternative:

> Ich habe es ausgeplaudert. (I blurted out the truth.)